# apache spark: How to read large text files from a directory and process them parallely?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a directory which has only text files. The size of text files can be large (in Gb’s). I have to process each file by sending first 100 lines of file to a python function. So for each file, the output produced by the python function for that file just depends upon first 100 lines. I can not use `wholeTextFiles` as it will load the content of all files into memory. One way is I can iterate over each file of the directory and process it using `textFile` api one by one. is there any better way ? Basically I want something similar to what `wholeTextFiles` does (i.e. one task for one partition of directory of files and all tasks running parallely) but I am interested in only first 100 lines of a file .

Comment: Spark is lazy. It won't evaluate until you perform the action. After reading the files. Either you can convert your RDD into Dataframe and select  top 100 rows or you can use zipWithIndex and filtering the tupple till 100.

Comment: try to understand more about transformations and actions. it holds answer to ur question...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you binaryFiles. It will give you path and Stream (DataInputStream). You can then consume this stream by reading only first 100 lines from each file.

A scala snippet.

```
binaryFiles("/directory").flatMap(x=>consumer(x._1, x._2.open))
```